# HTTP requests works only on Browser and not on real Android device

Tags: cordova, http, angular7, ionic4

i followed this Tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-your-first-ionic-4-app-with-api-calls-f6ea747dc17a/
trying to learn Ionic and dealing with HTTP . it works perfectly fine on browser . but after building an APK using " ionic cordova build android " the app stop sending HTTP get requests.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this native plugin :

```js
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
```

instead of

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

In ionic 4, you will have to do something like :

```js
import { http } from '@ionic-native/http';

this.http.get("URL", {}, {})
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);
  });
```

As you see, this is quite similar.

Learn more about it here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/